# Edit the same QList from different functions

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a single QList that is stored in a class which own a pointer to an instance of another class that has some functions to edit the QList. What I want to do is have a single QList editable from multiple classes in C++. When I remove an element from the list I would like to have it removed from the myvariable variable in classA too. The code is below

```
class classA {
    ...

private:
    ClassB *myclass;
    QList<mytype> myvariable;
}

class classB {
    classB::classB(QList<mytype> &variable) {
        this->myvariable = variable;
    }

    ...

private:
    QList<mytype> myvariable;
}
```

Comment: When you say a "single" QList, is that one per process, or one per object instance?  When you say "multiple classes", do you mean multiple object instances of the same class? or really you want one QList accessible from all classes?  Why not just make the QList a global variable, if you really want a single instance accessible by all classes.

Comment: the QList must be shared beetween two classes, A and B. But the class A own the instance of the list

Comment: FYI, `myclass` should probably be `std::unique_ptr<ClassB> myclass` if it owns myclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close just a couple of tweaks.  Make `myvariable` a reference, and initialize it in the constructor of classB, like this:

```
class classB 
{
  classB(QList<mytype> &variable) 
   : myvariable(variable)
  {
  }

private:
   QList<mytype>& myvariable;
}
```

Comment: it works, just a few things: is this the only way to do what I want? It seems a bit ugly to have all these & and initialize the variable myvariable in that way

Comment: This is C++, there is a mountain of different ways to do it!  :-)   There is some danger in this implementation assuming that the lifetime of the list is longer than `classB`.  You could use a pointer, or better yet a smart pointer if you are actually trying to share ownership of the list.  We could offer more suggestions on the design of what you are trying to accomplish if you shared more code.

Comment: But, directly answering your initial question, this is the way & its certainly the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a class c that holds a Static qlist. Then make it a common subclass of classes a and b.

EDIT:

```
class classC {
protected:
    static QList<mytype> mystatic;
}    

class classA : public classC {
private:
}

class classB : public classC {
    classB::classB(QList<mytype> &variable) {
        mystatic = variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: no, I need to pass the QList via constructors in the way I posted. I think it's possible to do what I want, but I don't know how

Comment: Dont See how YouTube needs interfere. Euthanasie my proposel.  You could Pass qlist via constructor and then assign it to Stativ member.

Comment: Cleartext: I dont't see how your needs for passing the QList via a constructor interferes with my proposal. You could pass a QList via a constructor and then assign it to the static member (just like you assign to your non-static member). ( sorry for the unclear comment in the first comment )